# Get hovered selector using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I think im being very silly here but here goes.

I have a menu with the basic structue:

```
<ul id="menu">
<li>
<h3><a href="/products/">Products</a></h3>
<span><a href="/products/">Have a look</a></span>
</li>
</ul>
```

What i am trying to do, is when the user hovers over the `<li>` change the text of the `<span>` to white. This is what i have:

```
$('ul#menu li').mouseenter(function(){
   $(this+ 'span a').css('color','white');
});
```

But its not working? I think its becuase $(this) is an object and i just want a string?

Comment: Is there any reason why not really use the `:hover` selector in pure css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why use JS at all?

```
#menu > li:hover > span a {
   color: white;
}
```

Working example at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/fZwJ7/

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. Didnt even think to use CSS

Comment: @Ryan I definitely think CSS is the way to go on this one, but do bare in [this in mind](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-hover) if you're using older versions of IE (< 8)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul#menu li').mouseover(function(){
   $(this).find('span a').css('color','white');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is best solved by CSS, not JavaScript.

```
ul#menu li:hover span a {
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use basic css for this :

```
#menu li span{
    color : #000000;
}

#menu li:hover span{
    color : #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: I think you'll find that you need to include the `a` in the selector too, otherwise the links will retain their default colour.

Answer (score 0):

You're overqualifying your #menu, so try this instead:

```
$('#menu li').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('span > a').css({'color' : 'white'});
});
```

Note you can also do this in CSS, however the `:hover` pseudo-selector is [not properly supported in older versions of Internet Explorer](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-hover) on anything other than `a`.

Comment: MSIE to the rescue again!  (NOT)